# Word for referring to the arts of the carpenter

Tags: single-word-requests, analogy

You can say "sartorial" to mean "of or pertaining to tailors of their trade." Is there an equivalent for carpenters?

Comment: Are you looking for an adjective?

Comment: @Jared: yep i am

Comment: To throw another 'sartorial'-like word on the pile: you could say 'tonsorial' to refer to something related to the trade of barbers (or anything to do with trimming): http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tonsor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, since *sartorial* comes from the Latin word *sartor*, then I guess the word pertaining to carpenters would be *lignarial*, coming from the Latin word for carpenter, *lignarius*.

This is not an attested word of course, but if your goal is obfuscation of the same sort as *sartorial*, then *lignarial* is the word you want to use.

Comment: oo deliciously abstruse..

Comment: Or.. a good word for a pickup game of balderdash.

Answer (score 5):

Unless the reader has a Latin dictionary on hand (or they search the web and hit this page) 'lignarial' would be inscrutable to most readers (unless that is your goal!)

But if we are using other languages to justify crafting words, 'carpenteria' means carpentry in Spanish, and the -al ending is a common way to turn nouns into adjectives, so may I suggest:

- carpenterial

In addition, the -or agent noun suffix is common in describing people in a given line of work: actor, governor, navigator, etc. Compare 'gubernatorial':

- carpentorial

I suppose the only added benefit these made up words would have when your readers see them is that they can probably guess what they mean. Again it depends on context. I would advise against using any of these unattested words in formal writing, for example (even 'lignarial' — and 'lignarial' carries a certain feeling of veracity which may cause folks to look the word up, leading to more frustration when they inevitably cannot find anything about it except this web page).

Comment: Are these adjectives real words?

Comment: @Steve Melnikoff, no, they aren't. That's the point of Jared's answer. (Although *lignarial* does seem to occur in the scientific names of some species.)

Comment: People make up words all the time. Like... internet.

Comment: +1, though the agent noun suffix -er is actually much more common in English than -or, see ["commentor vs commenter"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2350/commentor-vs-commentator).

Comment: Spanish for "carpentry" is "carpintería", not "carpenteria". :-)

Comment: If you google "carpentorial," you'll get some hits of people using it to mean "of or relating to carpentry." +1

Comment: I can make the claim that most people will look up words using Google... and thus the world dictionary of English is actually what websites Googles returns for the words... therefore, "lignarial" has now been added to the world dictionary of English, since users searching for it will find this page which gives its definition! In formal terms the definition would be something like: "of or pertaining to carpenters or their trade. used for purposes of obfuscation"