# What do you call who writes comments? Commenter or commentator?

Tags: meaning, technical, agent-noun-suffix

What should I call a person **writing/adding comments (by pressing "add comment" link**)? Commenter or commentator?

From a deleted answer, I understand that there are commentators (like those unilaterally commentating or closing questions) and commenters (those entering in discussion with others). Is it correct?

Isn't commenting by answering/questioning another commenter/answerer/questioner a live event? And what is the difference in these definitions between a commentator and an answerer?

Comment: See also [“Commentor” vs “Commentator”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2350/commentor-vs-commentator/2378#2378).

Comment: Thanks, I have seen it, I never ask without searching first.

Comment: The names of badges are more humorous and/or metaphorical than they are literal. For example, [answering a question more than 60 days later with score of 5 or more](http://english.stackexchange.com/badges/44/necromancer) doesn't make you a literal [necromancer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necromancy).

Comment: Oi, I did not come to this degree yet

Comment: @Rahul, humorous or derogative?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Commenter, for sure, *unless somebody is reporting on a live event*. According to the [Oxford American English Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/commentate):

> com·men·tate/ˈkämənˌtāt/
>
> Verb: Report
> on an event as it occurs, esp. for a
> news or sports broadcast; provide a
> commentary.

Comment: I don't foresee anyone commenting on a live event in this case!

Comment: I updated my question. Why had I been given the badge "Commentator: left 10 comments". Does it depend on amount of comments?

Comment: @GennadyVanin--ГеннадийВанин I realize this answer is long in coming, but it's just a play on words.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not keen on the choices offered. A commentator is one who gives on-the-scene reports of news events (whether recorded video or live tv). A person who writes comments (here, I believe we're talking about periodicals) is usually referred to as a 'columnist'. E.g., the UK Telegraph online has their columnists listed under the heading 'commentary'. It would never occur to me to call these writers commentators/commenters. They are columnists dispensing opinions.

Comment: The OP explicitly asks about people who are clicking the *add comment* link on a website to leave a comment, which presumably excludes people who write columns for periodicals.