# What do you call somebody who asks a question and somebody who answers a question?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, antonyms

What do you call somebody who asks a question and somebody who answers a question?

I have exhausted the thesaurus with no real luck... any ideas?

EDIT: It is in reference to this - or any other StackExchange - site in which the question is posed by X and answer is submitted by Y.

EDIT 2: In the context of StackExchange, and the fact I need plurality (something I neglected to mention oooops), I have decided upon "Posters" and "Respondents"...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you call who writes comments in this board? Commenter or commentator?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11397/how-do-you-call-who-writes-comments-in-this-board-commenter-or-commentator)

Comment: @kia: That odd question is about comments only, not asking and answering questions.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: You are right, indeed.

Comment: @slotishtype you should maybe answer your own question here with the EDIT 2 answer you chose. Yes, you are allowed to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Questioner/Asker, [Answerer](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/answerer), [Answerer](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/answerer)

> Noun
>   answerer (plural answerers)
>      1. a person or thing that answers or responds

Also see here: [Should I prefer "asker" or "questioner" for a person who asked a question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60179/should-i-prefer-asker-or-questioner-for-a-person-who-asked-a-question)

Comment: You can accept my answer as the answer to your question, questioner, and let me be the answerer of this question

Comment: Ah ha .. a witty aside...done.

Comment: +1 _(snicker)_ Based on your answer, that should have said _asker_.

Comment: hehe, got me...

Comment: Asker is the first thing that comes to my mind, but it always gets squiggly lines (spell check). If it's so intuitive to call someone who asks an asker, why didn't it become a proper word in the English (US) language? PS: So does answerer...

Comment: But those words that stab and tear at the wounds of the soul. That's (part of) why they gave you spelling error marks when you typed them.

Comment: @HenrikErlandsson what are you on about????

Answer (score 17):

May I suggest: Questioner/Respondent

Comment: You may....I'd upvote but the system won't allow.

Comment: I was going to say Questioner/Questionee. Respondant seems more professional.

Comment: Gotta throw my weight behind this one. The individual words may exist, but *Asker/Answerer* as a pairing? No way! Give me *Questioner/Respondent* any day!

Comment: Respondent doesn't imply an answer given, hence is not suitable as answer to this question. It is however a response.

Comment: I like Questioner but not Respondent because Respondent is kind of like Defendant.  It's a legal term.  Responder works better.  I also like Expert which someone proposed.

Answer (score 11):

You could consider  *Inquirer*, *Questioner* or, for instance *Interrogator*. Meanings differ slightly, I'd normally go for one of the first two. The third can be used when someone asks multiple questions, i.e., interrogates someone else.

Edit: *respondent* has been suggested by others.

Comment: It's actuall in reference to this, or any stack exchange site, in which questions and posed by "questioners/posters" and answers are submitted by "respondents/answers".  Trying to find the most appropriate usage though.  Cheers btw.

Comment: I agree with you, inquirer is the right word. Asker is not on the Cambridge dictionary

Comment: I way prefer 'inquirer' to 'questioner' the latter seems to have connotations of scepticism.

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes they're called *counselor* and *witness*.

Comment: lol I love the twist on circumstance. Bravo sir.

Comment: Querent and Oracle have a similar bent.

Answer (score 5):

Asker and responder come to my mind first - these terms may be weird in your use case though, as I have a technical background.

Answer (score 3):

Questioner and Answerer do work just fine in this context.

But other common ones, depending on context:

Questioner - asker, inquirer, querier, analyst, examiner, interrogator, investigator

I don't have any alternatives for answerer other than respondent

Answer (score 3):

In addition to suggested ones, you may even use **interviewee** and **interviewer** in suitable context.

Comment: Asker and Askee ?

Answer (score 2):

Try a thesaurus: [asker](http://onelook.com/?w=%2a&loc=revfp2&clue=asker) [answerer](http://onelook.com/?w=%2a&loc=revfp2&clue=answerer).  I like *enquirer* and *respondent*.

Answer (score 2):

I use *querent* for the person asking questions. In the Stack Exchange context, the folks who answer questions are *experts*.

Answer (score 2):

Very late update, but I believe the convention now to use *OP* (short for *Original Poster*) for the person asking the question?