# Terminology of roles in a Q&A: The "asker" and "answerer"?

Tags: terminology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do you call somebody who asks a question and somebody who answers a question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12999/what-do-you-call-somebody-who-asks-a-question-and-somebody-who-answers-a-questio)

If you have one person in the role of asking questions, and another person in the role of answering questions, are there one-word names for their respective roles?

In other words:

- The term for someone who asks a question = ('Asker', 'Questioner', ?)
- The term for someone who answers a question = ('Answerer', ?)

They all seem like awful terms- is there another way to refer to them?

Comment: what-do-you-call-somebody-who-asks-a-question-and-somebody-who-answers-a-questio: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12999/what-do-you-call-somebody-who-asks-a-question-and-somebody-who-answers-a-questio