# What do you call someone who is asking for information?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

A petitioner? I'm not sure... Any suggestions?

Comment: Duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/q/12999/3820

Answer (score 4):

*Inquirer* fits the best for the one who asks for information, in my opinion.

Comment: Absolutely the word!

Answer (score 1):

*Inquisitor* or perhaps *questioner*

Similar question here: [What do you call somebody who asks a question and somebody who answers a question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12999/what-do-you-call-somebody-who-asks-a-question-and-somebody-who-answers-a-questio)