# What do we call somebody who asks only puzzles

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What do we call somebody who asks only puzzles? Similar to this [Post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12999/what-do-you-call-somebody-who-asks-a-question-and-somebody-who-answers-a-questio) tells us the term somebody asks questions.

Answer (score 1):

How about a *riddler* or *puzzler*?

M-W:

> [*riddle*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/riddler): a
>   mystifying, misleading, or puzzling question posed as a problem to be
>   solved or guessed
>
> [*puzzle*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/puzzler): a
>   question or problem that requires thought, skill, or cleverness to be
>   answered or solved

A [*riddler*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/riddler) is one who speaks in *riddles* [TFD]. A [*puzzler*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/puzzler) is a person that *puzzles* [TFD].

Comment: I did search on the internet for "Puzzler". The results are showing "something that is difficult to explain or understand".

Comment: @Shiva It can also be a person who poses puzzles. I added a few more links.

Answer (score 0):

I like *riddler* best.  You may vary it with *gamester* if you like.

*A person who plays games.*

http://www.yourdictionary.com/gamester

Answer (score 0):

Consider ***sphinx***. In allusion to the [mythical, riddle-asking beast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphinx#The_Riddle_of_the_Sphinx), this term can also be used for persons who ask puzzles. For example, [from OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/186484):

> A person characterized by some quality of the Sphinx; *esp.* one who propounds or presents a difficult question or problem.