# Is there a word for someone who posts a "comment"?

Tags: single-word-requests, computing, agent-noun-suffix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you call who writes comments in this board? Commenter or commentator?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11397/how-do-you-call-who-writes-comments-in-this-board-commenter-or-commentator)
>   [Difference between “commentor” and “commentator”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2350/difference-between-commentor-and-commentator)
>   [Why do we say 'commentator' instead of 'commenter'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20080/why-do-we-say-commentator-instead-of-commenter)

I'm writing a bug report of a software which is about an Article Management Software and deals with a lot of comment issues. I need a word for someone who posts a comment. I thougt about the comment writer, author of the comment, etc. but none sounds what I want. Is there a word for someone who writes/posts a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use *commenter* or *commentator*, although correct it suggests heavy commenting in the style of scholar articles about an author. Therefore maybe *comment poster* if it's on a Web resource.

In your particular case, you could increase the use of the actor: i.e. *test participants commented about...*. Given that talking of the *participants* would imply that their main output is comments regarding what they have been shown.